# Splitting list strings in Python and testing for the date

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, date

I want to moves files from previous dates to an archive folder. I have a directory with neighbourhood databases that are updated regularly (daily, but sometimes multiple times a day). These databases look like this: `Database_NeighbourhoodA_v1.001_DT2020-05-11_c1.xlsx`
Where after `_DT` the date of the update is shown and after `_c` the `count/version` of the day is shown, so in this case this is the first update from yesterday, the second update would be denoted by `c2` etc. Then there is a subfolder in this directory called `Archive` in which I would like to move/save the databases from previous dates (together with replacing the version count `_c` to `_last`.

```
import os
import glob
from datetime import date
import shutil
import os.path

todaydate = date.today()

currentdatabases = glob.glob('./Databases/*Database_Neighbourhood*')

for database in currentdatabases:
    currentdatabases = str(currentdatabases)
    oldfiledate_part1 = currentdatabases.split("_DT")[1]
    oldfiledate_part2 = oldfiledate_part1.split("_c")[0]
    if oldfiledate_part2 != todaydate:
        lastfile_part1 = oldfile.split("_c")[0] + "_last.xlsx"
        lastfile_part2 = './Databases/Archive/' + lastfile_part1
        shutil.move(currentdatabases, lastfile_part2)
```

First I make a variable that is equal to today's date. Then I search for the neighbourhood databases in the directory by making use of `global` (there are other files in the directory as well). Then I loop through all these databases in the directory to see if the dates are not equal to the current dates and then move them with `_last` to the archive. I do this by splitting the path strings to the date parts and make a condition on that.

How can achieve the desired result?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide a few rows of your database? That way, any member would be able to reproduce your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the loop, you must loop through each database in currentdatabases, not currentdatabases itself. Specifying an example for your new output's name would be great.